# Opening pdfs from a list file which contains paths to pdfs

Tags: bash, shell, data-analysis

I have a list file of selected pdfs (each line contains a path to pdf). These pdfs are located in different directories which are several thousands in total. I am very new to using bash and struggling to open only those files which are listed in the list file. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: All of the answers in the link process ALL the lines in the file, which isn't what the OP needs.  I'm glad I got a more appropriate answer posted before it closed.

Answer (score 1):

If there are thousands of files listed, you probably don't want to open them all at once.  This little script opens the one you specify on the command line by number.  You could modify it to print out the name or search the list, etc.

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
    [1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]) N="$1" ;;
    *)  echo "Put a file number on the command line";  exit       ;;
esac
while read pdfpath; do
    if [ $((--N)) = 0 ]; then
        atril "$pdfpath" &      # Or evince, okular, etc.
        exit
    fi
done < listfile.txt
```

The opening `case` sets `N` to the first command line argument (`$1`) if it's a number but exits if a number wasn't specified.

`while read ... done` loops through the lines in your list file and reads each line in turn in the variable `pdfpath`.

`$((--N))` decrements the variable, so when it gets to zero it matches the comparison and enters the `if` clause.

The `&` causes the command to execute but control returns immediately so the script can exit and not tie up your bash prompt.